# How to decant beer from bottle

Tags: serving

I have an old bottle of Sahti, Samuel Adams, probably 3 years old, it's been kept properly, I noticed that it has a lot of sediment, don't know if it's normal or not, but regardless I want to try it. Is there a safe way to decant the beer, so the sediment or floaties don't make their way to the glass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like wine, pour into a glass while watching the sediment.
 Make sure the bottle has sat still for long enough that everything has settled. Stop when the sediment is about to pour out.
Enjoy.

Comment: If you are pouring for more than one person, do not lift the bottle vertically after you started pouring. Lift the lip just enough to stop the pour, but causing very little disturbance to the sediment.